# Acetaminophen after a heart attack

Tags: heart-disease, practice-of-medicine, heart-attack, medications, myocardial-infarction

My grandmother was prescribed Dolo 325 (acetaminophen or paracetamol) after she had an episode of a silent heart attack. The dose is to be taken twice daily. Can anyone explain how this treatment might work?

Comment: This is a very interesting and important question. I hope it receives the answer it deserves.

Comment: Are you sure it's acetaminophen, not aspirin?  Acetaminophen is generally for pain or fever, and post-MI has a better safety profile than NSAIDs.  I googled Dolo 325; it showed a mix of Tramadol/Acetaminophen, which would make it similar to other opioid pain medications like Norco (Hydrocodone/Acetaminophen).

Comment: I'm certain, it is acetaminophen

Comment: Could it be a placebo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we have no idea of the medical conditions of your relative.